# malicious dll making GET & POST requests to legit sites. What could it be doing?

Tags: malware, http, forensics

Relatively new to the DFIR scene.  We have an assumed breach scenario playing out right now and I noticed that there were some GET and POST requests coming from a malignant dll in a users temp directory.

Cool, the strange thing is that the domain the dll is making requests to will be something like `cnn.com` or `businesstrader.com/some-directory/some-file.css`

I figured it was getting instructions from a c2 server or maybe writing data to a file remotely somehow but when I follow the links in a secure browser, it just opens up to the actual site.

Can someone help me understand what the threat actor could be doing in this scenario please and thanks?

Comment: Most likely testing for internet reachability unless those pages can host user-generated content (e.g. comments). Look at the code and you'll know.

Comment: Twas domain fronting